# How do I retrieve a random value in multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, random, multidimensional-array, associative

I have an array which contains information on posts I have made.

```
$DexArray = array(

            array(
            'url'       => "http://i.imgur.com/ObXLdd6C.jpg",
            'headline'  => "Dronningens Nytårstale",
            'subline'   => "Tallene bag talen og årets spilforslag",
            'href'      => "nytaarstale.php",
            'postedby'  => "kris",
            'postedurl' => "https://www.facebook.com/dataanalyticsdk",
            'dato'      => "21. december, 2014"
            ),

            array(
            'url'       => "http://i.imgur.com/sxddhOe.jpg",
            'headline'  => "Endless Jewelry",
            'subline'   => "Are there really endless possibilities?",
            'href'      => "endless.php",
            'postedby'  => "Nikolaj Thulstrup",
            'postedurl' => "kris",
            'dato'      => "10. december, 2014"
            ),
```

It is stored in a multidimensional associate array. I am trying to retrieve a random 'href' value in the array and store it as a variable.

I have tried using the array_rand function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$k = array_rand($DexArray);
$v = $array[$k]['href'];
```

I get an error message saying: undefined variable: array in this line "$v = $array[$k]['href'];"

Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Error is pretty clear. Did you define `$array` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$k = array_rand($DexArray);
$v = $DexArray[$k]['href'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working debug :) [link](http://3v4l.org/EnST9) 
There was a lingering `,` in your thingy. And `$array` was never defined in the first place, so that's what the error was telling you about.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the code it will return the random value from the multidimensional php array.

```
<?php
            $filter_field = array();
            $original_items = array(
            array(1, 'stuff1', 'info1', 'response1', 'info1', 'response1'), array(2, 'stuff2', 'info2', 'response2', 'info2', 'response2'), array(3, 'stuff3', 'info3', 'response3', 'info3', 'response3'), array(4, 'stuff4', 'info4', 'response4', 'info4', 'response4'));

            for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($original_items); $x++) { 
               array_push($filter_field, $original_items[$x][0]);
            } 

            shuffle($filter_field);

            echo "<br/><br/><br/>";

            for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($original_items); $x++) { 
            $k = $filter_field[$x];
             for ($y = 0; $y < 5; $y++) {
                echo $original_items[$k-1][$y];
             }
             echo "<br/><br/>";
            }
            ?>
```

Here is another solution that will return the index of the random array.

```
    $var = array(  
                array("a", "one"),  
                array("b", "two"),  
                array("c", "three"),  
                array("d", "four"),  
                array("e", "five"),  
                array("f", "six"),  
                array("g", "seven")  
            );  
            // array_rand returns the INDEX to the randomly 
            // chosen value, use that to access the array. 
            $finalVar = $var[array_rand($var)];  

            print_r($finalVar);
```